# Django url - matching value from list/tuple

Tags: python, regex, django

Currently in my urls.py I have something like:

```
url(r'^(?P<my_var>:|var1|var2|var3|other_string)/rest_of_url'
```

it matches
`/var1/rest_of_url
var2/rest_of_url
var3/rest_of_url
other_string/rest_of_url`
I would like to have a list/tuple of variables:

```
VARIABLES = ('var1', 'var2', 'var3')
```

That could store variables that can be matched in my url.
However I do not know any django regex that could do that. To be precise, my goal is to have something like:

```
url(r'^(?P<my_var>:regex_matching_any_of_VARIABLES|other_string)/rest_of_url'
```

Comment: You would probably be better off validating my_var in your view and just returning a 404 if my_var is not in your list of accepted vars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a `'|'.join` on the tuple and add that to the pattern:

```
pattern = r'^(?P<my_var>:|' + '|'.join(VARIABLES) + r'|other_string)/rest_of_url'
url(pattern, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try out with two url patterns. Altough a bit verbose.
First it tries to match with your variables and then generic pattern.

```
VALID_VALUES = '|'.join(["var1","var2","var3"])
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^(?P<var_type>(%s))/rest_of_url/$' % VALID_VALUES,
                           'your_view'),
   url(r'^(?P<var_type>[\w\d-]+)/rest_of_url/$',
                        'your_view')

)
```